# Extracting metadata from large set of images

Tags: r

I have a very large set of images from a behavioural observation study. I would like to make a table of the file names of all the files and the timestamp when each one was taken. Because all of the files are in the same directory, I can easily get the filenames and some metadata using `fileSnapshot()`. I'd hoped for something simple like:

```
snapshot <- fileSnapshot('../data/raw/TMC')

snap <- snapshot$info %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::select(filename=rowname, timestamp=ctime)
```

However, because these files are copies, not the originals, the `ctime` variable shows when the files were *copied* and not when the photos were *taken*. I can see when the photos were taken by looking at File Properties in Windows Explorer so I know that info is stored with the file somehow, but I can't figure out how to access it.

I realize R is probably not the best tool for this job, but the rest of my workflow in R so a R-based solution would be best. But I'm open to other options. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with `file.info('../data/raw/TMC')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for the files' EXIF data, which contains a lot of different metadata, including the creation date.

There are a couple of libraries on CRAN which can help, but they may be a bit fiddly. They both seem to work by calling the ExifTools command line program, which they will both offer to install for you. I found the easiest to be exiftoolr.

```r
install.packages("exiftoolr")
library("exiftoolr")
library(tidyverse)   # this is purely so that I can easily show the results as a tibble
install_exiftool()
```

Now in the console you can do this:

```
> exiftoolr::exif_read(path.expand("~/Rplot.jpeg"))
# A tibble: 1 x 24
  SourceFile ExifToolVersion FileName Directory FileSize FileModifyDate FileAccessDate FileCreateDate
  <chr>                <dbl> <chr>    <chr>        <int> <chr>          <chr>          <chr>         
1 //XGGC.SC~            11.8 Rplot.j~ //XGGC.S~    32908 2019:12:30 14~ 2019:12:30 14~ 2019:12:30 14~
# ... with 16 more variables: FilePermissions <int>, FileType <chr>, FileTypeExtension <chr>,
#   MIMEType <chr>, JFIFVersion <chr>, ResolutionUnit <int>, XResolution <int>, YResolution <int>,
#   ImageWidth <int>, ImageHeight <int>, EncodingProcess <int>, BitsPerSample <int>,
#   ColorComponents <int>, YCbCrSubSampling <chr>, ImageSize <chr>, Megapixels <dbl>
```

So, programatically you can do this:

```r
my_dir <- path.expand("~/")
file_names <- list.files(path.expand("~/"), pattern = "*.jpeg")
creation_dates <- paste0(my_dir, file_names)    %>% 
lapply(function(x) exif_read(x)$FileCreateDate) %>% 
unlist

data.frame(file = file_names, created = creation_dates)

#>                      file                   created
#> 1 ed_to_AAU_transfers.jpeg 2019:06:27 17:14:27+01:00
#> 2                hist.jpeg 2019:12:30 09:14:36+00:00
#> 3               hist2.jpeg 2019:12:30 09:16:34+00:00
#> 4 LOS_plot_for_Kirsty.jpeg 2019:09:24 12:52:03+01:00
#> 5          mysterybin.jpeg 2018:07:28 22:17:12+01:00
#> 6               Rplot.jpeg 2019:12:30 14:25:07+00:00
#> 7             w46plot.jpeg 2018:06:05 17:38:17+01:00
```